# FragmentAdapter doesn't hold the good reference of the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently trying to work with fragment, but I'm stuck with an issue I can't solve.

I have one activity, which holds 4 different fragment. From this activity, I launch an ASyncTask which goes to the web and get different data I need, and then will send it to the fragments.

But, when my app gets killed and opened again, or when I change the orientation, my fragments are apparently recreated and my custom FragmentAdapter doesn't hold the good reference to the fragment.

Here is the code of my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    MyPagerAdapter fgsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //...
        FragmentManager fm = super.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fgsAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fm,this);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_pannels_pager);
        myPager.setAdapter(fgsAdapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ATaskGetUser task = new ATaskGetUser(callback, (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.PB_AsyncTask));
        task.execute();
    }
    //What's called by the ASyncTask onPostExecute()
    private void notifyDataChanged() {
        fgsAdapter.notifyFragments(user.getItems());
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<CardFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<CardFragment>();
        private Context c;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
            super(fm);
            CardFragment h = new HabitFragment();
            CardFragment d = new DailyFragment();
            CardFragment t = new ToDoFragment();
            CardFragment r = new RewardFragment();
            fragments.add(h);
            fragments.add(d);
            fragments.add(t);
            fragments.add(r);
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CardFragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.v("MainActivity_fgsmanager", "getItem()");
            CardFragment f = (CardFragment) this.fragments.get(position);
            return f;
        }
        public void notifyFragments(List<HabitItem> items) {
            for(OnTasksChanged f : fragments) {
                f.onChange(items);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what I want to be able to do, is to be able to call the onChange (an interface implemented by my four fragments), in my `notifyDataChanged` function. Is this possible, are am I thinking the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problems once with Fragments, I was losing the current fragment after every screen rotation.

I simply solved it by adding one line in the Fragment class (not in the parent FragmentActivity class):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rate_fragment, container,false);

    setRetainInstance(true);//Added not to lose the fragment instance during screen rotations

(...)
```

For your case where your app gets killed and opened again, I am not sure it will work though.

Comment: Sorry, I saw your answer, and then forgot to try it out. So, it seems to work, I might have to try it out a bit more. But anyway, thank you very much.