# Some fragments are lost on rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

In my `FragmentActivity` I use several fragments. when configuration changed(on rotation) system destroys and re-creates each fragment.
I try to use this re-created fragments

```
mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_frame);
```

and put it to new layout

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, mFragment )       
    .commit();
```

but meet with strange behavior: several fragments are lost. they are not displayed on the screen more. in their place is empty.
Although the logs show that fragments are re-creates fine, but further shows that the fragment is again destroyed, again created and destroyed again.

I build test project for show problem more clearly and without husk.
and that demonstrable results (*not enough reputation to insert pictures*)
[Activity started picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56123074/fragmentRetain/init.png)
[Activity rotated picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56123074/fragmentRetain/rotate.png)

A,B,C,D is a `fragments`
As you can see after configuration changed some fragments are lost (B,D)

tell me what I'm doing wrong

here's the code to help (Edit:push code to gitHub in order to make it easier to try)

```
https:// github.com/nailgilaziev/TestFragmentsRetain
```

p/s sorry about links

here log cat after I rotate device

```
MainActivity: onPause Activity
MainActivity: onStop Activity
MainActivity: onDestroy Activity
A: onDestroyview
A: onDestroy
B: onDestroyview
B: onDestroy
C: onDestroyview
C: onDestroy
D: onDestroyview
D: onDestroy
MainActivity: onCreate Activity
A: onCreate
B: onCreate
C: onCreate
D: onCreate
MainActivity: replaced
MainActivity: onStart Activity
A: onCreateView
B: onCreateView
C: onCreateView
D: onCreateView

<--before this point all fine and then strange behavior began
for the lost fragments(B,D) are performed unnecessary calls-->

B: onDestroyview
B: onDestroy
D: onDestroyview
D: onDestroy
D: onCreate
D: onCreateView
MainActivity: onResume Activity
```

Comment: Check my answer below and give it a try, don't forget to upvote if my solution works for you :): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630502/fragmentadapter-doesnt-hold-the-good-reference-of-the-fragment/16630812#16630812

Comment: @Yoann No, unfortunately it does not help.`setRetainInstance(true)` only stores the object in memory,but still is not added in new layout. I'll add a log cat on original question,maybe it will help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By breaking down your problem such that there are two Fragments instead of four, you will see that `onCreateView` gets called multiple times on the same Fragment when orientation changes. This is an indication that the same Fragment is being added/created more than once.

Basically, when orientation changes, your Fragments will be re-attached automatically so there is no need to perform a `FragmentTransaction` every time `onCreate(Bundle)` is called.

What you should be doing in `onCreate(Bundle)` instead is...

1. Null check the `savedInstanceState` Bundle that is passed into `onCreate(Bundle)`. -- If an orientation change occurs, `onCreate(Bundle)` gets invoked again and the `savedInstanceState` Bundle will become **non-null**. `FragmentActivity` saves data in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` before it is re-created.
2. If `savedInstanceState` is null, create your Fragments and attach them via `FragmentTransaction`. Otherwise, do nothing.

In summary, your revised code should resemble the following...

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.a, new A())
            .replace(R.id.b, new B())
            .replace(R.id.c, new C())
            .replace(R.id.d, new D())
            .commit();
}
else {
    a = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.a);
    b = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.b);
    c = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.c);
    d = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.d);
}
```

Also, side note, the `savedInstanceState` Bundle in the `onCreate(Bundle)` method of a `Fragment` will **always** be null, unless you save something to it in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`, so don't assume `saveInstanceState` will also be non-null in a `Fragment` when it is re-created, as it is in the case of a `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: yes. it helped me. thanks you. Well, now I'm going to carefully read the documentation

Comment: In my case I was displaying a GridView of images in my fragment, but I noticed after orientation change scrolling the grid showed what appeared to be phantom images behind the grid.  LogCat showed onCreateView being called multiple times - after doing a null check for saveInstanceState in my activity, the problem went away and onCreateView is only called once as expected - thanks Alex